# How to group image order by time from array

Tags: php, file, time, grouping

I have array of photo with filename and time. I want to find the photos which are taken in hour. For example, I have photos taken from 10.00, 10.15, 10.59. So when I search. I want these photo to be listed under 10.00.

I think it's something to do with `in_array` or `array_search`. But I still don't have an idea how.

Here is my array: **$pixArr[]**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7519.JPG
            [time] => 13:02
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7518.JPG
            [time] => 13:01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7517.JPG
            [time] => 13:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7516.JPG
            [time] => 11:39
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7515.JPG
            [time] => 11:39
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7514.JPG
            [time] => 11:38
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7513.JPG
            [time] => 11:29
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7512.JPG
            [time] => 11:26
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [file] => IMG_7511.JPG
            [time] => 11:26
        )

)
```

I expect it coming out something like this:

```
<a href="listPhoto.php?time=10-00">10:00</a>
```

**listPhoto.php**

```
<?
//now how to list files by hour???
?>
```

Comment: `array_filter` function

Answer (score 0):

you may use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) As @u_mulder suggested:

```
<?php
$pixArr = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7519.JPG',
            'time' => '13:02'
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7518.JPG',
            'time' => '13:01'
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7517.JPG',
            'time' => '13:00'
        ),

    3 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7516.JPG',
            'time' => '11:39'
        ),

    4 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7515.JPG',
            'time' => '11:39'
        ),

    5 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7514.JPG',
            'time' => '11:38'
        ),

    6 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7513.JPG',
            'time' => '11:29'
        ),

    7 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7512.JPG',
            'time' => '11:26'
        ),

    8 => array
        (
            'file' => 'IMG_7511.JPG',
            'time' => '11:26'
        ),

);

print_r(array_filter($pixArr, function($value){
    if($value['time'] >= '11:00' && $value['time'] <= '12:00')
        return $value;
}));
```

See Demo: https://eval.in/513466

Comment: kamal pal, that's a perfect script! And what if I want to find the starting time and the ending time from the array???

Comment: @Wilf you can use the same array_filter or simply loop through

Answer (score 0):

you can using `assort` This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their correlation with the array elements they are associated with.

I have been tried this problem.

```
$arr = [
[
    "file" => "IMG_7519.JPG",
    "time" => "13:02"
],

[
    "file" => "IMG_7519.JPG",
    "time" => "12:02"
],
[
    "file" => "IMG_7519.JPG",
    "time" => "15:02"
]
];

asort($arr); //sorting array
echo "<pre>".print_r($arr)."</pre>";
```

and this is the result.

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [file] => IMG_7519.JPG [time] => 12:02 ) [0] => Array ( [file] => IMG_7519.JPG [time] => 13:02 ) [2] => Array ( [file] => IMG_7519.JPG [time] => 15:02 ) )
```

Comment: Wida, how to get those files in 11.xx group together?